# How to enable Wcf help page with basicHttpBinding (SOAP, not REST)

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I am trying to enable ***Wcf Service*** Help Page in my Wcf service, but no attempt worked, no avaiable help page with service's methods descriptions under link `<.....{servicename}.svc/help>`

I tried any hint I managed to find, without result.

It is possible at all to enable automatic Help Page for wcf service with *basicHttpBinding* ?

My Wcf service is hosted in Asp.net application

here is my wcf configuration section from ***we.config***:

```
<serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="EcoscadaApi">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" httpHelpPageEnabled="true"   httpsHelpPageEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="EndpointBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_HvacControlService" sendTimeout="00:05:00" />
        <binding name="ecoWcfBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"  >
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="EcoSCADA.Web.Services.Wcf.BuildingComponentService" behaviorConfiguration="EcoscadaApi">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/Services/wcf/BuildingComponentService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ecoWcfBinding" contract="EcoSCADA.Web.Services.Wcf.IBuildingComponentService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="Metadata"  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
```

Any remarks/hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try [this](http://stack247.wordpress.com/2011/04/18/enable-wcf-web-service-help-page-in-web-config/):

```
<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DefaultEndPointBehavior">
        <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

**Update:** Looking at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230442(v=vs.110).aspx) I notice that they include a specific endpoint for the help page:

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="RESTWebServiceBehavior" name="RESTWebService">
    <endpoint address="" kind="webHttpEndpoint" behaviorConfiguration="RESTEndpointBehavior" contract="IHello" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this, however I still get blank page under the link .....{servicename}.svc/help

Comment: After struggling a bit with second article, finally it worked out! Thank you very much BCdotNET!

Comment: @robsonwk can you let me know what you did to get this working?

Answer (score 3):

[Help page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230442(v=vs.110).aspx) is available only for **webHttpBinding**